# What are good alternatives to: 'dramatically lowers the barrier to entry for'

Tags: synonyms

I'm sick of hearing the phrase 'dramatically lowers the barrier to entry'. Please help the world out by suggesting a simpler phrase or word to use instead.

Comment: Depending on the tone you're going for, "dumbs down" might work.

Comment: _Prevents `N`% entry_

Comment: @JohnLawler - that sounds negative...I understand OP is looking for a positive statement..or not?

Comment: It may be useful, however; that's preferred in science. In marketing, of course, things are different; but that's not my concern.

Comment: For one thing, barriers are not "lowered." I know it's used in the sense 'reduce' here.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you are referring to  the economic concept of *[barriers to entry](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barriers_to_entry)*:

> - In theories of competition in economics, barriers to entry, also known as barrier to entry, are obstacles that make it difficult to enter a given market.The term can refer to hindrances a firm faces in trying to enter a market or industry.

Alternative expressions to covey the same concept may be:

> - Make entry/access (to market) much easier for..
> - Facilitate  entry to markets for..
> - Promote access/ entry to markets for...

( from Wikipedia)

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for a context-neutral replacement, "drastically increases opportunities for/to/in" could work.